# Alternative to Eclipse PDT for exporting and generating PHAR archives

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana, phar

I want to create some PHAR Archives but did not find any good alternative to Eclipse for this purpose. Need a solution for maybe Aptana or a standalone solution.

Do yu know some programs for this?

Need it as a program for windows on my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP ships with a command line tool called .. `phar`, which allows you to create, inspect and modify .phar archives.